# Can shake generate dependency graph in graphviz format?

Tags: shake-build-system

Using `--profile` makes shake generate a `report.html` file from which one can run queries and generate a dependency graph of build rules. Would it be possible to get that graph in graphviz format instead of needing a browser to display it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run `--profile=report.json` then you get a JSON file containing all the data that goes into the profiling. From that, it should be quite easy to generate a GraphViz output. If there is demand, a GraphViz generation mode could be added to `--profile`.

However, past experience suggests that a GraphViz file of all dependencies is just too large to be practically viewed. To make the graph view practical you either need to group/filter the graph, or use a better graph viewer.

Comment: Yes, I do agree that "large" graphs are pretty much unreadable. I was just looking for a way to get the graph out of the report.html .

Comment: If it's useful, happy to take a patch adding it! Unfortunately no easy way to do so right now.

Comment: fair enough :) Will have a look and if it's not too involved, will definitely try providing a patch.